# How to prevent page refresh on update session Next 13 (app router) js

Tags: session, next.js13, next-auth

I am using NextAuth.js with React and Next.js, and I'm facing an issue with preventing a page reload during a session update. I have a function handleUpdateSession that uses sessionUpdate from next-auth/react to update the session information.
Here's the code snippet:

```
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";
const { data: session, update: sessionUpdate } = useSession();
function handleUpdateSession() {
  sessionUpdate({
    info: // Your info here...
  });
}
```

Additionally, I have a NextAuth.js configuration with a callback for JWT updates:

```
callbacks: {
  jwt({ token, trigger, session }) {
    if (trigger === 'update') {
      if (session.info) {
        // Updated value
      }
    }
    return token;
  }
}
```

The handleUpdateSession function is triggered in three scenarios (Signin, SignUp, and Update), and the session object receives the information sent during the update call, such as:

```
{
  info: // some info here
}
```